# Intellij - Revert Template Edit

Tags: intellij-idea

This is referring to the templates for IntelliJ found at:

Settings -> Editor -> File and Code Templates

I made changes to the Class template and completely broke my ability to create Class files in IntelliJ.  How can I revert my changes and put them back to the original values?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this one I solved right after posting.  There is a button at the top of the template dialog that reverts the changes back to the original value.

Maybe this will help someone in the future.